# Getting very large backup files from shared hosting

Tags: linux, vps, shared-hosting

I have very large project on linux shared hosting, I tried to backup web-site with cPanel, but it is excluding the folders which are very large (about 20 gb and ~300,000 files), I alos tried to archive it to small chunk of files with `tar` but shared hosting killing that process after about 30 minutes.

I'm trying to migrate from shared to VPS, how can I migrate the project?

Comment: Have you tried FTP, SCP, or SSH?

Comment: Or rsync over SSH.

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose I'd go with rsync over SSH. If the connection is broken, rsync can resume and it will only update the files that are different from the source server.

If you do want to use tar, I'd suggest using `nice` to avoid the process getting killed.